# inValid html - unexpected closing tag `</code>`

Tags: html, angular

The following code snippet was generated by the [`marked`](https://github.com/chjj/marked) markdown renderer, and is included in my angular 2 template.

```
<code>
@import { url(&#39;~/platform.css&#39;) };
</code>
```

However, it throws the following error:

```
Unexpected closing tag "code" ("
<code>
@import { url(&#39;~/platform.css&#39;) };
[ERROR ->]</code>
```

What is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to encode the content like

```
<code>
{{'@import { url(&#39;~/platform.css&#39;) };'}}
<code>
```

if it contains `{` or `}`

Comment: Is that angular2 compatible? Will that not try to bind it to a variable for that name?

Comment: No. See the `'` inside `{{'` and `'}}`. This binds it as literal string.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077960/eof-chars-in-html-when-merging-angular2-templates/39078039) question linked to your answer?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Well having implemented this solution, I am now facing that issue described on the link and am wondering if that is likely to be the same thing, or as I mention int he question, is it because I am merging files?

Comment: I see. I'm pretty sure it's the same thing. The only difference is that in this question there is only one line, while in the other questions there are multiple lines.

Comment: But I used the backticks in that one instead of the `'`?

Comment: But you commented that it didn't help to use backticks instead of `'`