# EOF chars in html when merging angular2 templates?

Tags: html, node.js, angular

I have a nodeJS application which reads all the `.md` files in a directory and then renders their contents as HTML using [`marked`](https://github.com/chjj/marked). I am then using the result as an Angular2 template.

However, I am now getting a console error like this:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("width="760" height="1300" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
</div>[ERROR ->]"): chapterComponent@1805:6
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("

<code>css
[ERROR ->]{{'
Page {
    background-color: white;
"): chapterComponent@395:0 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException {message: "Template parse errors:↵Unexpected character "EOF" …ckground-color: white;↵"): chapterComponent@395:0", stack: "Error: Template parse errors:↵Unexpected character…st:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)"}
```

[image]

I am not sure if this is because the EOF chars from the individual files being merged are coming across, or there is an issue with my `{` escaping as the error message is alluding too.

The snippet being referenced at the bottom of the error looks like this:

```
<code>css
{{'
Page {
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 17;
}
TextField {
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;
}
Image {
    margin-top: 20;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 80;
}
Button {
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;
}
'}}</code>
```

NB: `chapterComponent@1805:6` is the end of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

I think you need to replace each single `{` by `{{'{'}}` and `}` by `{{'}'}}` as the error message says.

**doesn't work according to the comment**

Try a backtick instead of a single quote. Single quote is only for single line strings.

```
<code>css
{{`
Page {
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 17;
}
TextField {
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;
}
Image {
    margin-top: 20;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 80;
}
Button {
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;
}
`}}</code>
```

Comment: Another way would be to replace each single `{` by `{{'{'}}` and `}` by `{{'}'}}` as the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

It happened for me because I mistakenly placed `template` url in `scss` place and `scss` url in `template` place. it might help you as the same error you will get and you no idea what is happening

#### wrong

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sd-select',
    templateUrl: './select.component.scss',
    styleUrls: ['./select.component.html'],
    providers: [SELECT_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

#### correct

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sd-select',
    templateUrl: './select.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss'],
    providers: [SELECT_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can make sure that you have correctly done the syntax, please do the ng build rather than using hot reloading with ng serve.